# 16166 display programming

Tags: display

Along with my z80 development board I found a 16166 16*1 display.

I have found datasheets for the electronics, it have 8 data (but can be run in 4 bit also) and 3 control, but I have failed to find any actual programming manual.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Is there a controller chip on the display? You might be able to find a data sheet for the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably this display: [MDL-16166-SS-LV](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/varitronix/MDL-16166-SS-LV/153-1077-ND/459204) with [HD44780](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf) compatible controller.

Comment: It takes a lot of pins; at least 4 data and 3 control. The easiest way if I need pins for other I/O is probably to give the display its own ESP8266 and just send text to it over mqtt, which I'm already using ;-)

Comment: Oh well, there is a library for this: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/LiquidCrystalDisplay
I can get away with only 6 pins.